# Is there an algorithm to find the Shannon entropy for text?

Tags: algorithm, text

I know the Shannon entropy for English is 1.0 to 1.5 bits per letter and some say as low as 0.6 to 1.3 bits per letter but I was was wondering is there a way to run an algorithm that looks at a large volume of text and then determine the expected value of the collective text is say .08 bits per letter of the collective text?

Comment: It's difficult to measure that in a completely meaningful way, as entropy is by definition a probabilistic measure.  I can compress any given text down to a single bit, using a compression scheme that maps that bit back to the original text.  And that's absolutely fine, if I only ever need to represent two different texts.  So in that context, the information content of your text is 1 bit.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there a way to measure the redundancy of different text? So say you have two sets of text with 1000 words, could you measure if one text is more or less redundant than the other text?

Comment: Not without some context.  It's possible that one of the texts was generated by a pseudo-random number generator, in which case it's completely redundant (other than the value that was used to seed the generator).  All you can say is that in the context of certain rules (e.g. predicting current letter from previous two letters), you can compress the text by a certain ratio.  But choose different rules, and the results will be different.

Comment: The basic problem is that you must figure out how "predictable" the next bit in a bit stream is, given what's gone before.  Though there are many different compression algorithms that make use of known predictable features, there is no way to quantify all the ways that something might be predictable.  Just think -- some friends you can predict word-for-word what they will say in a given situation, and some friends will use the same phrases over and over but in a different sequence, while other friends are totally unpredictable.

Comment: You'll get a reasonable estimate by compressing the text (eg: gzip) and look at the compression ratio. A "standard" text can probably be compressed downto 10...20 % of its original size.

Answer (score 6):

The mathematical definition of the [entropy rate of a language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_rate) is, if you have a source that generates strings in that language, the limit of the entropy of the n<sup>th</sup> symbol, conditioned on the n-1 previous ones (assuming that the source is [stationary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process)).

A good enough approximation of such a source is a large corpus of English text. The [Open national american corpus](http://www.americannationalcorpus.org/) is pretty nice (100M characters, covers all types of written texts). Then the basic algorithm to approximate the limit above is to look, for a given n, at all n-grams that appear in the text, and build a statistical estimate of the various probabilities that occur in the definition of the conditional entropies involved in the calculation of the entropy rate.

The [full source code](http://pit-claudel.fr/clement/blog/files/entropy-rate.py) to do it is short and simple (~40 lines of python code). I've done a [blog post about estimating the entropy rate of English recently](http://pit-claudel.fr/clement/blog/an-experimental-estimation-of-the-entropy-of-english-in-50-lines-of-python-code/) that goes into much more details, including mathematical definitions and a full implementation. It also includes references to various relevant papers, including [Shannon's original article](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/ms/what/shannonday/shannon1948.pdf).

Comment: N-grams are not as powerful as general data compression. N-grams will therefore overestimate the Shannon entropy. Compressors like PAQ hold the world record for compression and are the best Shannon estimator known to mankind at the moment.

Comment: @usr: Compression algorithms are highly dependent on data types; I'm not sure how valid a claim for world records might be. But indeed, evaluating compressibility is another way of estimating entropy.

Answer (score 2):

The Shannon entropy value for text is estimated. It is beyond human power to ever find out exactly. You can estimate it by running efficient compression algorithms over it (PAQ) or use humans to predict the next letter of a given string. Humans will do a good job because they apply semantic knowledge, not just statistical knowledge or syntactic knowledge.

Short answer: Try to compress the data/text you have as well as possible and calculate, how many bits you empirically needed.

It depends on the concrete algorithm what you can get the number down to. This will always just be an upper bound on the Shannon entropy (remember that the exact value will never be known).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you know of any software downloads that compress data/text and gives you the data compression ratio?

Comment: The compression ratio in "bits/character" is (compressedSizeInBytes / originalSizeInBytes * 8).

Comment: @PoloMontana: Just use your favourite compression tool, and compare the file size before and after.

Comment: @usr I'm not positive that what you suggest would be a good measure (though I agree it's on the right track). First off - we should stress that this is an _upper bound_ to the Shannon Entropy (SE). Second, we should compare the compressed size to the same text but randomly permuted. One could imagine that there is some compression that is encoding specific, this should not be counted as part of the SE. Presumably the permuted text can not be compressed as much as the original, and that difference is the crucial measure.

Comment: I have added emphasis on this being just an upper bound. Randomly permuting the input is likely to increase its true entropy because it adds information. Imagine a text like ABABABAB... which has almost no entropy. Permuting it adds real, true, uncompressible entropy. If you permute text you can only compress it using character probabilities which is very limiting.

Comment: @usr That's what I was trying to get at, a better estimate of the SE would be the comparison of a zipped `ABABABA...` to it's zip permuted form `ABABBAAABABA...` rather then the zip to unzipped `ABABABABA`. Also "It is beyond human power to ever find out exactly.", is true when considering an ambiguous corpus, like the frequency of every sentence that can and will be said. It can be computed exactly for a fixed corpus or a static language. Still, good answer and could be made better by giving a simple example to OP.

Answer (score 0):

Oli Charlesworth is correct, entropy is defined on probabilities, not text.

The only true way one can generate a measure of disorder for data is to use Kolmogorov Complexity.  Though this has problems too, in particular it's uncomputable and is not yet strictly well defined as one must arbitrarily pick a base language - as Oli puts it the "context".  This well-definedness can be solved if the disorder one is measuring is relative to something that is going to process the data.  So when considering compression on a particular computer, the base language would be Assembly for that computer.

So you could define the disorder of text as follows:

The length of the shortest program written in Assembly that outputs the text.

Comment: "Shortest program ..." is just another way of talking about compressibility.  The size of the program will be determined by the compressibility of the text, given a specific compression algorithm, plus the size of the code required to decompress.